# Javascript if/else error

Tags: javascript

I keep getting this error:- **It looks like your function doesn't return 'Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.' when the income argument is 75.**

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? cheers :)

```
var creditCheck = function(income)
if(income >= 100)
{
return "You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card.";
}
else 
{
return "Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.";
}


creditCheck(75);
creditCheck(125);
creditCheck(100);
```

Comment: You're missing a `{` after `function (income)` and a `}` at the end of your function; indenting your code will help you identify this type of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about opening and closing that function :

```
var creditCheck = function (income) {
    if (income >= 100) {
        return "You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card.";
    } else {
        return "Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.";
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VKbjn/)

Comment: It works! ...for some reason I thought the if statement was outside of the curly brackets. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var creditCheck = function(income) {
    if(income >= 100)    {
        return "You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card.";
    }     else     {
        return "Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.";
    }
};
```

Besides, you are returning a string, you have yet to print it to screen or console or you'll see nothing.